# Java inheritance questions

Tags: java

I'm new to java and trying to solve this question. I need to answer the `???` part in the code to make it returns true.

I cannot parse the syntax of class A. What's the `String name;` at the end of class A ?

```
class A{A(String name){this.name=name;}String name;}
class B extends A{[???]}
public class Exercise{
  public static void main(String [] arg){
    assert (new B().name.equals("Cell"));
  }
}
```

Comment: What exact problem are you having doing this?

Comment: that's all the information I got

Comment: It is only the declaration of the class variable *name*

Comment: "What's the String name; at the end of class A ?" It's a field. Try indenting the code normally and it should become more obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a constructor in `B`, which calls its parent's constructor.

```java
B() {
   super("Cell");
}
```

And the following is the complete code:

```java
class A {
    String name;
    A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    B() {
        super("Cell");
    }
}
public class Exercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert (new B().name.equals("Cell"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What other parts do you think are different in this answer? (I'm, asking that to get some insight into what you need to learn)